# How does Quaternion.LookRotation() works

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm trying to make a cube to look at the mouse i found the following code:

```
 RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, hit.point.z);

            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * 10.0f);
        }
```

I don't get it why did he subtract targetPosition from transform.position ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) `LookRotation(Vector3 forward, Vector3 upwards = Vector3.up)`

LookRotation transforms a direction vector into a `Quaternion`. In this example, he wants the angle between the two points. By subtracting the two position vectors, you can get the distance between the points and transform that distance vector into a `Quaternion`.

`upwards` is simply used as a reference. You can set it to anything you like, but if you leave it blank (as it is in this case) it will default to `Vector3.up`.